# Excel VBA - Add Minutes to a Date and Time

Tags: excel

I have a macro that I need help on, this last bit is throwing me for a loop.
So I have column L that is a mm-dd-yyyy date, column M that is a hh:mm time. Column N is a aggregate of those two into one date/time using the formula below:

```
Range("N2").Formula = "=CONCAT(TEXT(L2,""mm-dd-yyyy "")," & ",TEXT(M2,""hh:mm""))
```

It is set up to autofill that formula to however many rows of subsequent data there are.
I also have column AF that contains a value of minutes, usually 4-6 days worth. What I need to do is find a way to add that integer of minutes to the combined date and time, and quite frankly, I am stumped. the DATEADD function doesn't seem to like the origin being a formula, but I am a newbie at this and kind of at my wits end.

Comment: `=L2+M2` and then apply the appropriate `.NumberFormat`. Datetimes are just numbers, so add them together.

Comment: @BigBen the problem is I need to add the minutes (column AF) to the combined date and time in column N. Column N is a formula rather than a value so adding them in simple way isn't working.

Comment: `=L2+M2+AF2/1440`. Replace your formula in column N with this simpler formula.

Comment: You're trying to add minutes to a text representation of a date-time value

Comment: @BigBen Thank you!! Once I fixed the cell formatting, this totally worked. Occam's razor and all that good jazz